# Split only text on special characters, but not on numbers with decimal points

Tags: php, regex

I'm thinking about a special regexp problem in PHP, but I can't find an solution.
I try to split some text into terms to get simple words, numbers and web addresses.

So i decided to split on every non alphanumeric character ( \w ).

To work with different languages, I use \w with additional letters, like Ää éèÈ and so on.

Example:

```
20,000 15.20 This is at Text. Right?!
www.google.com Jean Béraud
```

Until now, i use the following regexp to split the text:

```
[^\w(äÄüÜöÖßèé)]
```

http://regexr.com?2uq98

Which works well in 80% of cases, but splits 20,000 into 20 and 000 also www.google.com into www google com

So i tried to hold the numbers together, but still split on points, like `Text.` to get `Text`

To match 15.20, the following works: `(\d+\.\d+)`, but how do I combine the negation with the other regexp string? The following will not work: `(\d+\.\d+)|[^\w(äÄüÜöÖßèé)]`?
And: how do I handle the web address?

Comment: Doesn't split on spaces work for you?

Comment: no, because i also need to split 'Text.' to 'Text'. spliiting und spaces will ignore !?.:,;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$result = preg_split('/\W*\s+/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/h0SwzA), Result:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "20,000"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "15.20"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "This"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "at"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "Text"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "Right"
  [7]=>
  string(14) "www.google.com"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "Jean"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "Béraud"
}
```

Q: Why does `\w` matches `é` in my example?

A: That's based on the local of the system the PCRE library is used on, from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.

Alternatively it might be helpful to specify the regex as working with UTF-8:

```
$result = preg_split('/\W*\s+/u', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Ensure `$string` is UTF-8 encoded. As UTF-8 is international, specific locale settings might not needed to be taken into account. Give it a try.

Comment: theoretically this work's, but not on my server configuration, because foreign letters will be matched as \W :-(   - i will investigate this again...

Comment: This sounds like a locale issue on the system which provides the pcre libraries. You might need to use some regex functions from the `mb_string` extension and/or properly check the encoding/charset.

Comment: It looks like, the `preg_split` does not exist in the `mb_string` world. On the other hand: you are using preg_split without an `mb_*` command and gets the right result. How are you doing this?

Comment: @TheBndr: I've added an explanation to the answer and there probably is another fix to this, please try.

Comment: thank you - i have played around with those mb_* things and find out, that `$string`was not UTF-8 `mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8')`. So I changed `$string`to UTF-8 by using `$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");` an now, `'/\W*\s+/u'` works very well. :-) Thank you so much!! Now I try to change your rexexp to split on `' ` at the beginning or end of the word, to split on `'here we go'`: `'here` the `here` an `go'`th `go` (without starting end ending `'`)

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the answer from @hakre and your example, I believe you should combine the two expressions in this way:

```
$result = preg_split('/[^\wäÄüÜöÖßèé]*\s+[^\wäÄüÜöÖßèé]*/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Your original expression successfully matched the appropriate characters (the `[^\w(äÄüÜöÖßèé)]` part).

The expression from @hakre added that there could be ANY NUMBER of these characters (even none of the characters) and should also be followed by one or more instances of whitespace (the `\s+` part).

When you combine the two ideas, you get `[^\wäÄüÜöÖßèé]*\s+[^\wäÄüÜöÖßèé]*`, which basically translates to

> any number of characters that are not in this character class, followed by at least one whitespace character, then possibly followed by any number of characters that are not in this character class

or

> one or more whitespace characters, and any number of characters that are not in this character class, either before or after

As a test, I used this text sample (I assume you want to match French characters):

```
20,000 15.20 This is at Text. Right?!
www.google.com Comme son élève, où dois-je aller voir Jean Béraud?
```

and this regular expression:
**EDITED**

```
/[^\wßàâäèéêëîïôöœùûüÿç]*(^|$|\s+)[^\wßàâäèéêëîïôöœùûüÿç]*/i
```

through the same site that @hakre used:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/MqztVt

**END EDIT**

This test showed that the expression will split even if the word begins or ends with one of the special characters. I added the `/i` switch at the end of the expression to make the match case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! `/i`was an very helpful hint.  >I assume you want to match French characters< not only French. There are different textmessages with different names in, from all over the world. Of course those names have national characters, like Béraud, Müller, and so on. Using your link (http://codepad.viper-7.com/sQ3WTX) i notice no split at the end of `Béraud?` in order to get `Béraud` without `?` On the other hand, it works for `Right!?` ??

Comment: I corrected the expression in the answer (and added a new link) so it will work at the beginning and end of the string as well (and ignore any beginning or ending punctuation) - If you want to match more than French characters, add them into each character class. You could use one expression with all the special characters you can think of, or you could use for each language. Depending on where you are using this, there may be better ways to parse your string - for instance, if the string contains $20,000, you will get 20,000 and won't know whether it's dollars, pounds sterling or lira

Comment: If you want currency symbols to be retained, you could add them to the appropriate character classes.

Comment: Thank you, for that update. I will keep that solution in mind, for future use. Especial if `\w' will not work.Thank you! +1  For this specific problem, the solution from @hakre does better fits my needs...